# SELECT CASE - THEN - WHEN query throws an error

Tags: sqlite

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE var(name VARCHAR(255),integer INT(5),string VARCHAR(255)); -- my variables

CREATE TEMP TABLE param(name VARCHAR(255),integer INT(5),string VARCHAR(255)); -- my parameters

INSERT INTO param (name,string) VALUES('search',''); -- assigning my parameters
INSERT INTO param (name,string) VALUES('page',1);
INSERT INTO param (name,integer) VALUES('rows',10);

INSERT INTO var (name,integer) VALUES('initindex',( (SELECT integer FROM param WHERE name='page') - 1 ) * (SELECT integer FROM param WHERE name='rows')); --calculating my variable using the parameters

SELECT CASE (SELECT string FROM param WHERE name='search') -- querying
WHEN '' THEN (SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET (SELECT integer FROM var WHERE name='initindex'))
ELSE
    (SELECT * FROM clients
    WHERE id LIKE '%'||(SELECT string FROM param WHERE name='search')||'%'
    OR name LIKE '%'||(SELECT string FROM param WHERE name='search')||'%'
    OR first_date= (SELECT string FROM param WHERE name='search')
    OR last_date= (SELECT string FROM param WHERE name='search')
    OR pass LIKE '%'||(SELECT string FROM param WHERE name='search')||'%'
    ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT (SELECT integer FROM param WHERE name='rows') OFFSET (SELECT integer FROM var WHERE name ='initindex'))
END
FROM clients;
DROP TABLE var;
DROP TABLE param;
```

When I execute the whole query I get an error:

> [19:07:08] Error while executing SQL query on database 'DataBase': only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression

Also when I execute every single subquery, it results in just an unique row.
Because table `var` and `param`, which simulate to be variables and parameters like in MySQL syntax, always will return just one value.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: the problem is that it throws an error **only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression**. See the code please.

Comment: If I tell you that it is not possible to use CASE this way, your actual problem is not solved.

Comment: sorry, didnt understand at all what you said, so the problem is the syntax of CASE? i need help please, it has me stuck til now

Comment: the problem is that somewhere there is a multiple result inside the CASE and idk where.